# A New Word Order

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking

These ten words are arranged in order according to a certain property they share:

> festive
>   fixture
>   salient
>   resolving
>   recline
>   accessory
>   advise
>   headlight
>   redcoat
>   programming

Where should each of the following four words be inserted into the list?

abbreviate
twelve
humdinger
anecdote

What is the property shared by all fourteen words?

**Hint**

> A word's meaning is not relevant to the property in question.

Comment: In looking for a pattern among these words, I realised for the first time that the word "salient" has an alien in the middle!

Comment: uh oh. rand's back. answer fast!  :)

Comment: Wow, all 10 of the example words have 3 vowels (depending on your y-tolerance). Then only one of the additional 4 has 3 vowels... I wonder what the statistical odds of that are.

Comment: Ideally, the correct answer would also include the full sorted list of 14 words.

Comment: Once the property is found, then sorting the list becomes trivial, or so I assume!  :)

Comment: Does it have anything to do with translation into another language?

Comment: hmm, I can see a Festive Humdinger or a Salient Mixture. Maybe an Advice Accessory will help me find the pattern ;D

Comment: My brain is on fire. This one is tough. Time for a break!

Comment: @CodeNewbie "Does it have anything to do with translation into another language?" not really

Answer (score 47, accepted):

That was a real humdinger.  Now I'm feeling festive.

> Roman numerals.
>  Each word has, somewhere after the first character, a string of Roman Numerals, evaluating to a number.  Let the property be that number.  Then we get this ordering:
>  fest**IV**e = 4
>  abbre**VI**ate=6
>  f**IX**ture=9
>  sa**LI**ent=51
>  twe**LV**e=55
>  reso**LVI**ng=56
>  re**CLI**ne=151
>  a**CC**essory=200
>  ane**CD**ote=400
>  a**DVI**se=506
>  hea**DLI**ght=551
>  re**DC**oat==600
>  hu**MDI**nger=1501
>  progra**MMI**ng=2001

Comment: In that case, wouldn't mixture be 1009?

Comment: he's looking past the first character, otherwise even the original order is wrong

Comment: Nope, @Zikato is right. I goofed.  I had fixture and changed it at the last minute.  Argh!